# Native error when trying to implement libwebp

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, webp

I seemed to be getting a

```
JNI- java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native error: method not found
```

when I try to implement `libwebp` into my project. I followed this [link](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/faq#how_do_i_use_the_libwebp_java_bindings_in_my_android_project).

and it first gave me an error that it couldn't find the lib `"webp"`. Then I used `System.loadLibrary("MYPROJECT");` and it fixed the error, but generated another one saying

```
Native error: method not found
```

Every function from `libwebp` and `libwebpJNI` are generating the error, so it may have something to do with the native C code.

Any help?